# Is ssl CName important for search engine?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, seo

My site is under cloudflare and of course I am using free ssl from their side.

So, what what can I have sanctions on the site from the search engines while using free ssl?

Or what benefits will I have after dedicated ssl?

[image]

Comment: For SEO purposes this is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical perspective some reasons  to use the non-free options:

- You may need to support truly ancient SSL/TLS implementations that still require that your domain is in the Common Name of the certificate and which won't support the Subject Alternative Name SSL/TLS extension that allows multiple domain names in a single certificate.
- You might have sites such as `store.uk.example.com` that aren't matched with a wildcard `*.example.com`

Otherwise as far as I know what counts is that your site uses correctly configured TLS, not the price of certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dedicated SSL/TLS certificates, use Let's Encrypt. Don't waste money on those certificates from Cloudflare or anyone else.

Unless you're a large corporation I don't think there are any benefits to paying for SSL/TLS certificates.

Comment: we are having own letsencrypt cert, but with cloudflare proxy,  i can see cloudflare's ssl in browser...

Comment: Then you're not using your own Let's Encrypt certificate. Perhaps you've misconfigured something.